# Building only changed Modules in Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, devops

currently I am working for a company which has a rather large Maven Java project in place. The full build job on a dev machine might take up to 23 minutes. This of course is pretty redundant, since a developer builds the project multiple times a day, only changing some of the java classes.

I am wondering generally, if there is a better solution to this.
I read, that there are maven plugins allowing iterative builds. But all I saw was POC, no real production ready solution.
Another interesting solution seems to be Gradle Enterprise with its build cache. Reading the documentation, I understood that the CI Server stores the artifacts in a central build cache, allowing other developers to pull those. This reduces overall redundancy while building, since only the artifacts changed get builded.
Right now, dev snapshots get saved into the nexus. Is it maybe somehow possible to use those to shorten the build time?

Do you have any experience in this regard? How do you managed to solve this problem? I really can't imagine that we are alone with this issue.

Tell me when you need more context, I am being really general in my question. Any helps / hints are appreciated!

Comment: First what really takes 23 minutes? How much time take the tests? Which Maven version? JDK Version are you using ? Why is a build needed on a dev machine? Do you have a CI solution? How many modules / Classes / Tests do you have? Do you use parallel build?

Comment: It takes 23 Minutes to build the project, inlcuding a frontend and a backend component. The Unit tests take about half of the execution time. Maven version is 3.3.9, JDK 8 U212. Devs want to do a local build to test changes locally. There are 45 modules, and yes we use mavens capability to parallel build on multiple threads.

Comment: Reading your question I would think that you search for inefficiencies in our lifecycle. Of course there is room for improvement. But I think it would be more scalable if we enable devs to reduce the redudancy in their builds. What do you think

Comment: You need 10 minutes for tests? How many tests do you have ? Unit Tests? Furthermore why not using a most recent version of Maven? What is needed to test local changes? Running unit tests within your IDE? How long does a build including tests run on your CI ? running also parallel? via `-T ..` ?